# Find files with extension in directory and subdirectories?

Tags: python

I want to make a Python script to quickly organize my files on my desktop into folders based on extension. Basically, how could I use a loop to take a file, do something to it, move on to the next file, and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you need is probably contained in the [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) library, more specifically in the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) bit of it and the [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) one.

To explore a directory tree you can use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) and to move files around you can use [`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).

---

**EDIT:** a small script I hacked together to get you going:

```
import os
import shutil as sh
from collections import defaultdict

DESKTOP = '/home/mac/Desktop'

#This dictionary will contain: <extension>: <list_of_files> mappings
register = defaultdict(list)

#Populate the register
for dir_, dirs, fnames in os.walk('/home/mac/Desktop'):
    for fname in fnames:
        register[fname.rsplit('.', 1)[1]].append(os.path.join(dir_, fname))

#Iterate over the register, creating the directory and moving the files 
#with that extension in it.
for dirname, files in register.iteritems():
    dirname = os.path.join(DESKTOP, dirname)
    if not os.path.exists(dirname):
        os.makedirs(dirname)
    for file_ in files:
        sh.move(file_, dirname)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not exactly an expert, but I should be able to figure it out!

Comment: @lucase.62 - I added a small script to get you going. What it does, it create a directory for each extension type and move in it all the files with that extension. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend os.walk from the module [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) and [list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) of the filenames